# Any country name in current default locale

Tags: android, localization

What I want do do is to provide a ISO 3166-1 country code and retrive the name of that country in the current locale. For those of you who are familiar with iPhone, I have an an example of exactly what I want to do:

```
NSLocale* currentLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString* countryName = [currentLocale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode value:@"NO"];
```

In this case the variable `countryName` would contain "Norway" given the iPhone was running in an english locale.
What I have understood so far is that to get the current locale in the Android SDK by a simple static method of the Locale class.

```
Locale currentLocale = Locale.getDefault();
```

But Im stuck here...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Locale l = new Locale("en", "NO");
String norway = l.getDisplayCountry();
```

works for me. Just replace `"NO"` by the country you want and it should give you the name in your current default locale. The `"en"` is just there to fill in some language but it should not matter which you use (At least I hope that works for all combinations - have not tested them all)

Comment: Thanks, you could also just omit the language and get the correct result. So `new Locale("", "NO").getDisplayCountry()` would render the correct result aswell.